# Initialize a traveling wave in a 1D gas?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, waves, simulations

I am trying to initialize a **traveling** wave for a 1d simulation as one can see from the attached figure.
[image]

Such that it will be **traveling to the right**. 
However, I cannot initialize the right velocity profile, and this makes the initial pressure distribution tends to be more uniform to reach the same pressure of the surrounding fluid !

Can any one provide some support?

Comment: can show a diagram of how it breaks into two rarefaction waves?

Comment: @udiboy, sorry, I missexplained myself. see the Update

Comment: What is the medium in which the wave is propagating? And, more specifically, which model are you using for your simulation?

Comment: @user23660 I am using the 1d euler equation, and the gas is simply air (ideal ).

Comment: Doesn't seem right to me to use the Euler equations for a linear advection problem. Shouldn't you just use $\rho_{,t} + u\rho_{,x}=0$ (using the [comma notation](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/General_Relativity/Coordinate_systems_and_the_comma_derivative) for the derivatives)??

Comment: @KyleKanos , I was thinking the same as you, however, shouldn't the 1D Euler equation be able to describe such phenomena? I know tht with the advection equation can give the right behaviour, however, It will be difficult to adapt it to the Bondary condition  I am using!

Comment: @user2536125: The linear advection assumes that $P_{,x}=0$; that is: you have an isobaric system. If you can initialize your code to have a constant pressure, then the Euler equations will work. However, due to numerical accuracies, this may not be the case and the advection equation should be precisely what you want.

Comment: @KyleKanos what do you mean by Initializing the code with a constant pressure? do you mean the above profile or the same pressure all along the tube?

Comment: Would http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/ be a better home for this question?

Comment: @user2536125: I mean it as having the same pressure in the tube; but by having that, you are *idealizing* the Euler equations *into* the 1D advection equations.

Comment: @KyleKanos: Since the maximum perturbed pressure is 6 times greater than the ambient one I think that idealizing the system wouldn't work.

Comment: This question is better suited for http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @user23660: I believe that the over-pressure is due to the *incorrect* initialization. A 1D traveling wave is the propagation of an over-*dense* region (i.e., square wave); that particular problem requires an [advection equation](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/329/lectures/node93.html)

Comment: @KyleKanos: Or, possibly, this is a problem on propagation of a nonlinear wave (Riemann type solution) leading to formation of shock. 1D Euler code could potentially handle this. But anyways, its up to OP to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

We are trying to get the *simple wave* solution, so one can assume the dependence of the functions defining the solution (namely $u$, $p$ and $\rho$) only on a single combination of variables $x$ and $t$. In case of weak sound wave this combination would be $x - c t$, but nonlinear effects would makes this more complicated. Nevertheless, we still can choose one of the functions, for example $\rho$, as an independent variable on which the other two would depend and write 
$$
\rho = \rho(x,t),\quad p= p(\rho), \quad  u = u(\rho) .
$$

We can than substitute these into continuity equation and Euler equation:
$$
\dot{\rho}+\rho' u + \rho \frac{d u}{d\rho} \rho ' = 0, \tag{1}
$$
$$
\frac{du}{d\rho}\dot{\rho}+ u \frac{du}{d\rho} \rho' + \frac{c^2(\rho)}{\rho}\rho ' =0,\tag{2}
$$
where $\rho'= \dfrac{\partial \rho}{\partial x}$, $\dot{\rho}= \dfrac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}$. The local speed of sound is defined by $c^2(\rho)= \dfrac{d p}{d \rho}$ and could be found using adiabatic equation for an ideal gas.

For the initial conditions on the velocity $u$ we could solve (1) and (2) for $\frac{du}{d\rho}$ (also eliminating $\dot{\rho}$):
$$
\dfrac {du}{d\rho} = \pm \frac{c(\rho)}{\rho},
$$
where two sign choices correspond to simple waves traveling to the right (+) and left (-). Integrating we obtain:
$$
 u = \pm \int \frac{c}{\rho} d\rho = \pm \int \frac{dp}{\rho c}.
$$
The final explicit result could be obtained by using the adiabatic process equation: $p \rho^{-\gamma}= p_0 \rho_0^{-\gamma}$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, I think I did not explaine myself well. By 1D Euler I meant, the continuity, energy and momentum equations without source terms (no friction or heat transfer). so I can't see how your development can make a pure right(or left) traveling wave!

Comment: That's what I used. Only instead of energy equation I used (equivalent for our purposes) adiabatic condition.  The fact that the wave is traveling in one direction is expressed in dependence $u(\rho)$ and $p(\rho)$.

Comment: What do you mean by "pure" traveling wave?  For a single fluid, the Euler equations will not give a simple traveling wave solution.  Only two options exist: expansion wave or compression wave.  Expansion waves are described in the above answer and involve characteristics spreading out.  Compression waves involve characteristics converging to form a shock wave.

Comment: @SimpleLikeAnEgg , by a pure traveling wave, it's like if one had a disturbance source at the left end of the tube, this source will generate a pulse which will automatically travel to the right direction

Comment: @user2536125 Disturbances tend to spread out in all directions in fluids.  With periodic boundary conditions you could potentially initialize a traveling sound wave.  A sound wave is a very weak wave, but with the Euler equations it would eventually form shocks.  Otherwise, if you make the left boundary condition be that of higher pressure and density you will create a rightward traveling shock.  Good luck.